# Wordpress - Show my blog along with main site

Tags: php, wordpress

I already have my main PHP based website running in the root folder of my website. Lets call it www.example.com. I have about few pages. Some of the navigation links are:

Home | Services | About Us | Contact Us

I wanted to add a Wordpress blog to this.. So heres what I did.

Home | Blog | Services | About Us | Contact Us

Please note that I have now created a sub-folder called "blog" in the root folder of the website and I have uploaded all the Wordpress "files" into the blog folder. So if I want to access my blog, as of now, I would visit: www.example.com/blog

So far, its ok. Now when I add new posts to the blog, I do NOT want people to see the "/blog" in the URL, when they try to read the posts. I went through the following link, but it does not help: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

The above link will help if people just want to host their Wordpress site and nothing else. Its just helpful to keep the root folder clean and still access the URL from the root folder. But thats not the case with me. I already have PHP based website running in root folder. I just want 
the blog to be an addition, yet skip showing that its added in another folder.

I made the following changes as well in admin panel of wordpress:

In "Settings > General" page:

WordPress Address (URL): www.example.com/blog

Site Address (URL): www.example.com

In "Permalink Settings" page, chose this option: http://www.example.com/sample-post/

Now, the home page & other pages load fine.

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I visit: **www.example.com/blog**, it says:

"This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?
It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help."

1. I do not understand why I see the above when I expect to see the post. There is a sample post of Hello Word. I expected to see a link to that, but that did not happen. Why is this happening?
2. Further, if I click on the Home link, it gets me to the homepage of the website, which is correct. But if I click on the "Sample Page" menu link or "Hello World" link under "RECENT POSTS", the following URL appears in address bar: 
   www.example.com/hello-world/
   But, it does NOT show me the post. Instead it loads the index.php page of the root folder of my website, which should not happen. It appears as if the CSS file is not loaded as it removed all the CSS. So the index.php page's CSS stripped version appears when I visit: www.example.com/hello-world/

I have tried to find solutions for this, but all of them lead to the "Giving WordPress Its Own Directory" post. And the solution mentioned in that page, does not apply in my case. How can this be solved? All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure without checking the actual problem practically but still you can try giving your `wp site address` to -> `www.example.com/blog`

Comment: How the links to "Home | Services | About Us | Contact Us" look like? I mean, are you using `mod_rewrite` or they are just `services.php` like? I think I can come with a solution

Comment: Thanks for replies. I have given individual replies below. Kindly check them.

Comment: I'm wondering now... Does wordpress have permalinks for categories too? if not, then things may get complicated again...

Answer (score 1):

**Method I**

This would be dirty, and I'm not sure if this would even work, but try to do the folowings (I hope your site is procedural and you're not using any framework, otherwise this would complicate things a little):

1. Put the blog in your document root, so all WP links would work "naturally".
2. Put your site files into `site/` subfolder.
3. Now we'll do some magic with `.htaccess` and rewrite your "site" links by putting the following code right after `RewriteEngine on`:

   ```
   # do this for all pages of your site:
   RewriteRule ^services/?$ /site/services/$1 [L,QSA]
   # now let's try to trick WordPress and swap / with /blog
   # so users will see /blog in adressbar, but we'll show the WP homepage
   RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,QSA]
   ```
4. Now we should make WP think that `/blog` is actually `/`, so it would not make any suspicions. Put the following script in the `index.php` file of Wordpress, before any other code:

   ```
   if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ){ // original site homepage requested
       include('./site/index.php');
       exit;
   }

   if( trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') == 'blog' ){
       $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';
       $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
   }
   ```

I haven't tested anything, but you should play around with these.

**Method II**

I'm not an advanced WP user, but if playing around with permalinks suggestion from @bingjie2680's answer would change the urls, than you can then try only one more thing in addition to that answer. Add something similar to the following lines to .htaccess that's in your document root (not WP's one):

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(services|about|or_other_stuff)/?$
    # Rewrite the request to call the WP index.php.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Maybe there are other methods, maybe the true solution would mix both of this.
Keep trying.

Comment: that is also a solution. good post. and thanks for writing up the rewrite rules. +1

Comment: @s3v3n Thanks for the comment. I tried method 2, but it has lead me to 500 Internal server error, throughout the website and the blog. I am wondering what I did wrong. Also in the first line of the rewrite rules, do I have to specify the link names or the links to actual php files, ex. services.php, about.php? I am currently using rules as you have mentioned in Method2, with the exception that I have replaced links with names of my links. One of the links is "contact us", so there are gaps in it. Please let me know what I could do to fix this. Also I am trying to skip /blog in URL. Thank you.

Comment: It's always a good idea to check the error log. You have to write the urls as they were before, so if you had `/services.php` in url, you should put `services.php` there. The first row is just saying: "If the request url is NOT 'services' or 'about' or ..., use this rewrite rule so WP can see it's links, otherwise just use it as it is, so if you haven't any framework there, you probably should put file names. It wouldn't be a good idea to have gaps in url (you meant spaces, right?). Cheers

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work, but it simply doesn't. All the articles that I came across give answers for WPMU sites & for just an alternate directory fix. But nothing for a PHP based website and WP blog in parallel. Can anyone be done about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be a problem if you do the following things:

- no need to change anything in your original site.
- create a folder called blog in your root directory and place all wordpress files in here.
- follow the quick five-step to set up your blog
- your wordpress url and site url **should both be** yourdomain.com/blog
- In "Permalink Settings" page, chose this option: www.example.com/sample-post/
- keep your menu like: Home | Blog | Services | About Us | Contact Us
  with 'blog' pointing to yourdomian.com/blog

Now if your click on the blog menu, your site url will be yourdomian.com/blog, but if you click on one of posts say 'hello world', then your url will be yourdomian.com/hello-world.

Comment: I doubt this would work, because WP will not receive any requests. He will just get a 404.

Comment: if you have a .htaccess file in root with correct configuration, your won't :)

Comment: @bingjie, thanks for the reply. I tried it out. The points that you mentioned, worked. But they only took me to the point of displaying www.example.com/blog. When I click on Hello World post, the URL reads: www.example.com/blog/hello-world/. I also added the rewrite rules that s3v3n mentioned in Method2. But that kind of broke the whole website, including the blog. Now I get 500 Internal Server Error whenever I visit the website & blog. Did I do anything wrong?